# Stuck with initialize package (Dart)

Tags: dart

I have been trying this the whole day: I use initialize in several places in my library and then I have some example code in several HTML+Dart files.

For one set of html+dart it works for another it does not - it simply never calls the init methods even when I copy the files contents and they are identical.

I have tried restarting DartEditor and Dartium and so on, I just don't understand how it can work for one file set and for the other not when they have the same content and are in same relative paths...

Please advise where should I look for problems because this behavior is beyond me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you make this project (or a reduced version which still allows to reproduce the problem) available on GitHub?

Comment: Are all your libraries which should be initialized be reachable from entry_points registered in the initialize transformer config?

Comment: No, only the main file. Do you mean all html files that include dart files that call 'run()' should be included as entry_point during development in dartium?

Comment: I haven't used initialize directly myself yet but this is how transformers and entrypoints usually work (for example in Polymer which also uses initialize). I'm pretty sure it is necessary to add each html file to the transformser config. Each entry_point is a complete Dart application.

Comment: Ok I got it now, I did not know that the transformers kick in while in development, I thought it is only useful when compiling to JS. I have added the files one by one and now it it working, thank you

Comment: Usually they shouldn't be necessary during development but this isn't always the case (for example Angular 1). I don't know for initialize but I think it's better to check this before searching somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add each HTML to the initialize transformer configuration `entry_page` list, which references a Dart file by a script tag where you want initialize to take effect.

Each HTML page with a Dart script tag is a self-sufficient Dart application.